# Can Cyberpunk Red be used to create campaigns after the Unification War?

Tags: cyberpunk-red

I'm considering getting the corebook, but first I would like to know how feasible would it be to use it to create a campaign after the Unification War. I know Red takes place right after the 4th Corpo War and its Night City is still part of NoCal, but I like the idea of instancing a campaign on an independent NC.

Does the core book allow a campaign like that? Or at least does it provide tools to create something like that?

More specifically, I would like to know whether the gameplay rules and assets can be used to create campaigns that happen later than "The time of the Red". My concern is that the gameplay and rules are restricted to 2045, and couldn't be used on a 2071 setting.

Comment: Can you specify what tools you think you need? That way it will be easier to answer whether or not the book contain these tools.

Comment: My bad. I expressed myself incorrectly. What I meant was whether I can use the gameplay rules and pre-made gear (and/or gear creating rules, should they exist) from the corebook to create a fair/enjoyable campaign. What I had in mind was creating a campaign in 2071, roughly one year after the end of Unification War.

Comment: This is not really the site for that kind of question. Whether or not a campaign is enjoyable is mainly dependant on the GM. Whether or not a book is suitable for a campaign that _you_ find enjoyable is almost impossible to answer.

Comment: To get an answer to this you could look into reviews or ask on a forum. I'm sure there are fans of the book somewhere who can explain all its contents and discuss it with you.

Comment: @Anagkai You have returned.

Comment: I think I'm missing the point here. Forget I said "enjoyable". I would like to know whether the rules and pre-made weapons, roles and lifepaths be used to create a campaign in 2071, or are they too strict or era-dependant to be used on different eras. Just like I can't use a Tormenta rulebook to create a DnD campaign, or a Cyberpunk 2020 rulebook to create a 2077 campaign. For example, I don't think creating an Arasaka Exec PC in Night City would be feasible in 2045, while it is in 2077.

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect what you mean. Asking whether or not the rules prevent a game in this era seems a reasonable question.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I am indeed, I had a question to ask.

Comment: This question is fine. An expert in Cyberpunk can answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> More specifically, I would like to know whether the gameplay rules and
> assets can be used to create campaigns that happen later than "The
> time of the Red". My concern is that the gameplay and rules are
> restricted to 2045, and couldn't be used on a 2071 setting.
>
> I would like to know whether the rules and pre-made weapons, roles and
> lifepaths be used to create a campaign in 2071, or are they too strict
> or era-dependant to be used on different eras.

Cyberpunk was originally built using the Interlock system, that was also used for Mektzon Zeta, a completely different roleplaying game and was 99% compatible with minimal conversion. Later they worked on the Fuzion system which was a splice of Interlock and HERO system, again with an emphasis on convertibility, such as for their Bubblegum Crisis RPG.

Philosophically, R. Talsorian has never encouraged people NOT to use their mechanics for a campaign due to some minor or even major change in timeline, which is very different from the D&D timelines from 1st to 5th edition where game mechanics change and the backstory also changes (c.f. forgotten realms).

So your question boils down to "Can I use the rules and equipment from Cyberpunk Red 2045 in a campaign that takes place 24 years later?"

The answer is mostly Yes.

The clothing, equipment, and NPCs will all be 24 years older. Major changes that take place in 2071 will be political, and to some degree, Net based technology changes. How you resolve things like:

- attack rolls
- dodge
- skill resolution
- social checks
- driving a vehicle
- doing a black market purchase
- calculating the damage of a firearm
- resolving how your damage interacts with armor

these and most other rules will not need to be changed. Only a handful of things, like upgraded guns (we still use 1911 .45 ACPs after 111 years), and any other small improvements will have to be revisited.

But overall,

Human beings still purchase pants and put them on one leg at a time.

Solos still buy guns and ammo and smartlinks.

A 2071 campaign would most likely be a "supplement", but there's no need to scrap everything you learned from Cyberpunk Red. As the Game Master, it's up to you. Mechanics have little or nothing to do with what year it is. That's just setting gear, customs, and NPC write ups. COOL is still COOL, and bullets still kill.